# Display Address with strings using MapKit in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview

I am building an iPhone app in which i am just having the users address as a string and i am not getting any latitude or longitude for this, i want to show this address in the map view so is their any appropriate solution for doing this please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should show the map view using user's address.

[Get latitude/longitude from address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503100/how-to-get-latitude-longitude-by-address-with-iphone-sdk)

http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/

[Get street address at lat/long pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158557/get-street-address-at-lat-long-pair)

https://github.com/tylerhall/CoreGeoLocation